# qtwebkit-opensource-5.0.0-beta2 build error(target:linux-g++-64,params:--qt --only-webkit --no-webkit2)

Tags: qtwebkit

when i trying to build it i get this error:

```
Encountered 3 configuration warning(s):

! QtQuick module not found, QML APIs will not be built

! Missing QtWidgets module, disabling WebKit1

! Missing QtTest module, disabling DumpRenderTree, WebKitTestRunner and tests

WebKit is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.

...

Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: core
```

whereas i installed qtbase-5.0.0-beta2 and libQtCore libQtWidgets libQtTest are exist

in usr/lib but libQtQuick not exist.

the 258. line of qtwebkit-opensource-src-5.0.0-beta2/Source/WTF/WTF.pro file cause error

above.the line seems such:

```
QT += core
```